# Is there an easy way to un-root Android 2.2 on Droid X rooted via z4root?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x, unrooting, z4root

Is there an easy way to un-root Android 2.2 on Droid X rooted via z4root?

The reason is that I would like to apply a Gingerbread 2.3 update from Verizon, and that update ALWAYS fails to install.

Since I never had a custom ROM on the phone, my first guess is that the problem may be due to being rooted, but I don't see an "Unroot" option in z4root.

Please note that factory reset is NOT an answer I'm looking for.

Comment: How exactly is the update failing? Any error messages? The more information you provide - the easier it would be to diagnose and offer ideas.

Comment: @Chahk - see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15797/ota-gingerbread-2-3-update-fails-to-install-on-droidx-rooted-stock-froyo-2-2-1 for details of the failed update (this question is specific to "how do I unroot", since it's quite possible that the update fails for a different reason, AND I'd like to learn how to unroot independently of update failure)

Comment: Out of curiosity: what version of z4root do you have?

Comment: @eldarerathis - 1.1.0 z4root

Comment: Aha, the unroot button was added in v1.2.0. See my answer, maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z4root added an "Unroot" button in version 1.2. Version 1.3 added "force unroot" (not entirely sure what that means). You can grab the most recent version from [the XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953), then you should be able to simply hit "Unroot" and be on your way.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Didn't solve my OTA problem though :(