# OTA Gingerbread 2.3 update fails to install on DroidX (rooted stock Froyo 2.2.1 / unrooted back)

Tags: 2.2-froyo, 2.3-gingerbread, motorola-droid-x, ota-update, z4root

I was trying to install the Gingerbread (Android 2.3) OTA update available from Verizon for my Droid X.

However the update ALWAYS fails to install. It downloads fine, pops up a message saying that the update (**4.5.605.en.US**) is about to install and needs a reboot, then reboots when I OK it.

**After the reboot, it pops up "Update Status: The Software Update Failed" error box.**

---

My only possible suspicion as far as the reason is that my DroidX is rooted via z4root - I posted a separate question on how to un-root it ( [Is there an easy way to un-root Android 2.2 on Droid X rooted via z4root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15760/is-there-an-easy-way-to-un-root-android-2-2-on-droid-x-rooted-via-z4root) ) in case that suspicion is true.

**UPDATE** - I unrooted using latest z4root version. The problem with OTA was NOT fixed.

Comment: You may need to SBF back (unroot) to stock Froyo before taking the update.  Although, if you are going to do that, there are probably SBF files for Gingerbread already floating around out there that you can use instead.

Comment: @shambleh - unroot via z4root didn't work :(

Comment: Probably going to need to do the SBF then.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have read (in some instances) rooting the Droid X can prevent an OTA upgrade from being applied.  If that is the case here, you can perform an operation to return the phone back to its stock state.  In the case of the Droid X, this would be referred to as SBF.  An SBF file is used with a corresponding piece of software (like RSDLite for windows or sbf_flash in Linux) to completely reset the phone.  Here is a site with the files and tools used - [Droid X SBF files](http://sites.google.com/site/1kdsdroidx/).  There are many sites and videos that can walk you through this process.

Your best bet is to SBF back to .602 and then you should be able to take the update, but you will lose root and your phone will be fully reset.  As with everything root-related, you are fully responsible for any issues with the phone.  I, nor any others members of this site take responsibility for any issues or damages you run into with your handset.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid a full reset... thanks for the info anyway. I now have extra incentive to look at CM instead of stock OTA since I'll have to fully back up and reset anyway :)

Comment: @DVK Understood.  My DX is on Liberty 3 right now and it's a pretty good ROM (CM is still in nightlies for DX,last I checked).